# comparing a javascript array with a result

Tags: javascript, validation

I have the below code which checks my dynamically produced offhire boxes to see if there is an integer value present onsubmit. If i were to check the sum of the array at the end to see if all boxes added together was bigger than 0 how would i accomplish that.

```
function validateoffhire(form) {
    var num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
    var test2Regex = /^[0-9 ]*$/;  
    var num2 = num1.value;

    var i=0;
    var offhire1 = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
        offhire1[i] = document.getElementById('offhire1' + i);
        var offhire2 = offhire1[i].value;
        //if(nameRegex.match(pro[i].value)){

        if(!offhire2.match(test2Regex)){
            //alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)
            inlineMsg('offhire1' + i,'This needs to be an integer',10);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

many thanks for any help

steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code by adding an accumulator inside your loop, then check the accumulator outside the loop:

```
function validateoffhire(form) {
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
  var test2Regex = /^[0-9 ]*$/;  
  var num2 = num1.value;
  var accumulator = 0;

  var i=0;
  var offhire1 = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
    offhire1[i] = document.getElementById('offhire1' + i);
    var offhire2 = offhire1[i].value;
    //if(nameRegex.match(pro[i].value)){

    if(!offhire2.match(test2Regex)){
      inlineMsg('offhire1' + i,'This needs to be an integer',10);
      return false;
    }
    else{
      accumulator += parseInt(offhire2);
    }
  }
  if(accumulator > 0){

    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are saving all the values in an array. so u can add up all the values using a loop.

```
var totalValue = 0; 
var i=0;
while(offhire1[i])
{
totalValue += offhire1[i] ;
i++
}
if(totalValue)
{
// Non zero
}
```

Could you be please be more specific if im wrong.

Comment: `totalValue` is truthy for negative values, though. I would really check for `> 0`.

Comment: I have put it in this way since the question was to check if its greater than zero.

Answer (score -1):

You have to:

- Convert input values to a Number
- Use the `forEach` function of an Array to add the values together.

Like:

```
 function validateoffhire(form) {
var num1 = document.getElementById('num1');
var test2Regex = /^[0-9 ]*$/;  
var num2 = num1.value;

var i=0;
    var offhire1 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
offhire1[i] = parseFloat(document.getElementById('offhire1' + i));
var offhire2 = offhire1[i].value;
  //if(nameRegex.match(pro[i].value)){

  if(!offhire2.match(test2Regex)){
        //alert("You entered: " + pro[i].value)
inlineMsg('offhire1' + i,'This needs to be an integer',10);
return false;
}
}
var sum = 0;
offhire1.forEach(function(a) {sum+=a});
// here, sum is the sum of offhire1's values
return true;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't consider forEach safe for cross-browser compatibility just yet.